# Glass material reflecting weird when looking from side

Tags: cycles-render-engine, glass, hdri

I have a 3d model:

[image]
[image]

And when I look front the side, it looks like this:
[image]

It shows the HDRI completely.

I want it to look like this from all angles:[image]

But for some reason, the side shows the HDRI instead of the inside of the light.

Not sure why it's doing that. Help would be great!

Thanks
Daniel

(Note: The material is a principled shader with an index of refraction set to 1.500. And A transmission value of 1.5.)